# How to know notional character type in Java?

Tags: java, unicode

Method `Character.getType(char)` returns integer. Of course, I can compare it with all constants like `OTHER_PUNCTUATION` constant and deduce type. But there are dozens of these constants and it seems not good to code all manually.

Is there any function, which can convert from `OTHER_PUNCTUATION` to "Sm" Unicode category?

Comment: Isn't `MATH_SYMBOL` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

All of these constants such as Character.OTHER_PUNCTUATION aren't used in the JRE implementation. There are no references to them in the JRE source code. They are just defined there but not used.

So, I would say there is no other solution than to iterate over these 30 constants and to determine the type.